# Can we open firebase deeplink in apps WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview, firebase-dynamic-links

Some months ago our client has requirement like this, when he sends a emails to app users with a Refer a friend URL, on click of URL in the email, app users should navigated to Refer A Friend screen in the app.

To Achieve this we used Firebase Dynamic Links to create links with fallback urls. We also have a notification center in our app where all notification gets shown, on clicking on particular notification the detailed notification is opened on a WebView. Now if my WebView contains a deeplink created with Firebase Dynamic Links, it does not open or throws error: `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`.

Can I open these links in apps WebView itself? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Dynamic Links are expected to be handled by Google Play Services on Android. If the FDL was forced to be opened in a WebView, it throws a `net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME` error. I suggest removing the override in the WebView, or have a RegEx filter to allow FDLs to be launched outside the app. The FDL clicked should still open the "Refer A Friend" screen if the app is configured to receive the link.